# watching for events in web3 v1.x.x

Tags: web3js, events

I deployed a contract and would like to watch for events on that contract.

```
var access_manager_erc20_abi = require('./AccessManagerERC20_abi.js');  //To read the abi.
```

//In this js file i export abi into a variable and use it while creating instance of contract below.

//Smart contract address

```
var AccessManagerERC20ContractAddress = "0x3267ced1528c7eabe69bd129b3d0faf9986d6b55";
```

//creating instance of contract

```
AccessManagerERC20Contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(access_manager_erc20_abi,AccessManagerERC20ContractAddress);
```

watching for events, followed documentation from https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#events

```
AccessManagerERC20Contract.events.getAccessERC20Event({
    filter: {_producerGatewayID:acc[1]}}, function(error, event){ console.log(event); })
.on('data', function(event){
    console.log(event); // same results as the optional callback above
})
.on('changed', function(event){
    // remove event from local database
})
.on('error', console.error);
```

when I try to execute this piece of code, it says

> TypeError: AccessManagerERC20Contract.events.getAccessERC20Event is
>   not a function

Can someone help me please. I am using web 3 v1.0.0. beta.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your event actually called `getAccessERC20Event`? Could you share your contract code or ABI?

Comment: Try `AccessManagerERC20Contract.getAccessERC20Event().watch(function (error, result){ //do something with results here })`

Comment: It would be helpful to see your ABI. Maybe it isn't in proper JSON format?

Comment: @smarx, yes the event name is correct. Here is the ABI code https://github.com/katkol/Share/blob/master/AccessManagerERC20_abi.js

Comment: @Gabe I get similar error with this code as well, TypeError: AccessManagerERC20Contract.getAccessERC20Event is not a function

Answer (score 1):

I will just point to another question that you just asked because this seems to be the same problem:

[using abi generated by truffle in DApp](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46748/using-abi-generated-by-truffle-in-dapp/46749#46749)

If you look at your abi-file it is the same problem and you need to call:

```
AccessManagerERC20Contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(access_manager_erc20_abi.abi,AccessManagerERC20ContractAddress);
```

Comment: Hi, after changing the abi part the event also worked. Cannot point out the reason behind though.

Comment: Also I am using ws provider instead of http.