# using abi generated by truffle in DApp

Tags: web3js, truffle, dapp-development, nodejs

I use truffle to deploy contract to ganache network. I like to use the json file generated by the truffle in the DApp rather writing messy ABI into it. I tried the below piece of code and it gives error.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var publish_service_abi = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./PublishService_abi.json', 'utf8'));
console.log(publish_service_abi); //prints the contents of the abi
var PublishServiceContractAddress = "0x0da136781e562e28fb1c0b3efc8ce9d8b4e226f2";
PublishServiceContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(publish_service_abi,PublishServiceContractAddress);
```

Here is the error that I get when I run the application.

> Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when
>   instantiating a contract object.
>       at Contract (/home/ltu/Ganache/node3/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:70:15)
>       at new Contract (/home/ltu/Ganache/node3/node_modules/web3-eth/src/index.js:147:22)
>       at initweb3 (/home/ltu/Ganache/node3/app.js:32:34)

Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understood correctly the file PublishService_abi.json is the output of truffle in the build folder - right?

If yes then this file contains more than just the abi - so to fix your problem simply change your last line of code to:

```
PublishServiceContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(publish_service_abi.abi,PublishServiceContractAddress);
```

Answer (score 1):

The file generated by truffle doesn't contains only the ABI but more information. In your case you need to pass `publish_service_abi.abi` to your contract in order to make it work.